# ¿Como puedo hacer que mi form detecte mis validaciones al insertar un elemento dinamico?

Tags: jquery, formularios, validación

Buen dia, tengo un problema y espero puedan ayudarme

1. Tengo una Tabla (T1) la cual contiene información de productos, esta es generada a travez de una consulta en la BD con databales y tiene un input type=check por fila
2. Al seleccionar algun input de la T1 se activa mi funcion la cual almacena dentro de un arreglo el id del elemento seleccionado

   ```
   function seleccion(){
         $(".Select").each(function () {
            let id = $(this).attr("id");
            let existe=false;
            let tr=$(this).parent().parent();
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                for(let i=0;i<arrSeleccionados.length;i++){
                    if(arrSeleccionados[i].identificador==id){
                            existe=true;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if(!existe){
                    let articulo={
                        identificador: id[1],
                        desc: tr.siblings("td:eq(1)").text(),
                        unidad: tr.siblings("td:eq(2)").text(),
                        almacenada: tr.siblings("td:eq(3)").text()
                    }
                    arrSeleccionados.push(articulo);
                }
            }
        });
   }
   ```

3. Despues de agregar ejecuto otra funcion donde agrego a mi Tabla 2 (T2) el elemento que seleccionaron en la  T1 con la diferencia de agregar un input type=text

```
function mostrar(){
        let impresion='';
        if(arrSeleccionados[0]!=""){
            for(let i=0; i<arrSeleccionados.length;i++){
                impresion+=`<tr>
                        <td>
                            <div align="center"> 
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="chksl_`+arrSeleccionados[i].identificador+`" class="seleccionados"  data-position="right" checked=true/>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            `+(i+1)+`
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            `+arrSeleccionados[i].desc+`
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            `+arrSeleccionados[i].unidad+`
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 validate">
                                <input
                                    class="form-control e_requerido e_rango focused text-left"
                                    data-rango='{"minimo":"1","maximo":"`+arrSeleccionados[i].almacenada+`","mensaje":"Debe almacenar una cantidad entre 1 y  `+arrSeleccionados[i].almacenada+`"}'
                                    min=0
                                    name="Cantidad`+arrSeleccionados[i].identificador+`" id="Cantidad`+arrSeleccionados[i].identificador+`" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        
                </tr>`;
            }
        }
}
```

4. agrego con $(#id).html(impresion) a i tabla;
5. La T2 se encuentra dentro de un Form el cual sí envia los datos que ingreso sin embargo no toma encuenta mis validaciones las cuales estan en mis clases e_requerido y e_rango, estas validaciones funcionan en otros archivos sin problemas pero este es el primer archivo donde se generan elementos (inputs) dinamicos con jquery, quisiera saber el porque no me detecta estas validaciones y si hay algun modo de resolverlo
6. Algo curioso es que si genero un elemento estatico aunque sobrescriba la tabla en este elemento si fucionan las validaciones
[![muestro que la validacion funciona][1]][1]

Comment: Seria mejor que muestres el codigo. Te recomiendo leer [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: acabo de actualizar espero sea mas entendible, gracias por la recomendacion

Comment: puedes mostrar como haces uso de la clase para validar ?

Comment: con include a travez de un archivo .php el cual unicamente contiene scripts para el funcionamiento de la pagina, ahi se llama el script de validaciones `$(".e_requerido").each(function (item) {
  $(this).rules("add", {
   required: true,
   messages: { 
    required: "Campo requerido" 
   }
  });
 });` <br>@Richard

Comment: ok, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código de como utilizas la validación, para que sea mas entendible el funcionamiento o el como lo bienes haciendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude resolver el problema realizando dos cambios

1. En lugar de redibujar la tabla agrego las columnas una a una [aqui esta un ejemplo](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/JQuery/3874-Agregar-o-quitar-filas-editables-de-una-tabla.html)

2. Una vez tengo la fila (es inportante tener un id en el td a insertar el input) lo agrego mediante el siguiente metodo

```
   function crearInput(identificador){
        let td='#td'+identificador;
        let t = $("<input/>",{
            type:'text',
            class: 'form-control e_requerido e_rango focused',
            name: 'Cantidad'+identificador,
            id: 'Cantidad'+identificador,
            'data-rango':'{"minimo":"1","maximo":"30","mensaje":"Debe 
         almacenar una cantidad entre 1 y 30"}'
        } ).appendTo(td);
        
    }
```